# Make a Scope condition check if an Array has at least one element of another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to make a scope that brings back all the buildings that have at least one of the uses that I send in an array as a parameter.

My Building model has a column `types_of_use` with the attribute `array: true`

How could I go about making a scope that checks to see if at least one of the values I send is in the array and keeps the result as an `ActiveRecord_Relation`?

```
Building.first.types_of_use # Returns ["Offices", "Comercial"]

uses = ["Hotel", "Comercial"]

Building.with_uses(uses) # Should return the first building
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is PostgreSQL then you'd want to use the [`&&` (overlaps) operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE):

> `&&`
>   overlap (have elements in common)
>   `ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1]`
>   `t`

You'll also want to use the [array constructor syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
array[?]
```

as ActiveRecord likes to expand placeholders whose values are arrays as a list of comma separated values.

Putting that together, your scope could look like:

```
def self.with_uses(uses)
  where('buildings.types_of_use && array[?]', uses)
end
```

or, if you prefer to use the `scope` method to define scopes:

```
scope :with_uses, ->(uses) { where('buildings.types_of_use && array[?]', uses) }
```

but ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) so I usually use explicit class methods for scopes with arguments.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you a lot!